# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

the only code i have in the doinbackground is  'URL(params[0]).readText()' i chacked params[0] its the write url and also the interet permition is declared in the manefest file im so confuse write now if any on know the error i did please let me know

'

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private  val TAG : String  = "mytag"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var downloadData = DownloadData()
        downloadData.execute("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml")
    }

    inner class DownloadData: AsyncTask<String , Void , String>(){
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
           return  URL(params[0]).readText()
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
            Log.d(TAG , "onpostExecute : link received is $result ")
        }
    }

}
```

'

Comment: Please paste all the excetion detail. The same code works fine in my project.

Comment: i found the solution i put in  a comment

Answer (score 0):

after some seach here is the solution
in the android mainfest add the falwing 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"'